# MySQL Query - the Clause `where (varchar)` returns items starting with a number only. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an interesting result and don't understand why.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM items im
 WHERE ItemNumber
```

`ItemNumber` is a `varchar(50)`.

The results of this query is returning all items that the `ItemNumber` starts with a number.  If the `ItemNumber` begins with a letter, it is excluded.

Does anyone have an explanation why the query interacts in this way?

Comment: I assume you are aware that the where clause is not clear - it seems either unneeded or incomplete. (The reason it works the way it does is discussed below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL will return all rows with the ItemNumber starts with a number which is `greater than equal to 0.5 and less than equal to -0.5`. It consider all number `greater >= +/-0.5 as true`. And `where` clause works based on true or false only.

```
true >= -0.5  > false < 0.5 <= true
```

*Very smartly, mysql* consider All `>= +/-0.5` number as 1 (true). It takes **true** for **rounded non-zero values**.

IF you write

```
SELECT * FROM items im WHERE 1; // will return all rows.
SELECT * FROM items im WHERE 0.5; // will return all rows.
SELECT * FROM items im WHERE 0.4; // will return nothing.
SELECT * FROM items im WHERE 1 and 0.2; // will return nothing.
SELECT * FROM items im WHERE 0.3 or 0.5; // will return all rows.
```

Answer (score 6):

This is MySQL's strategy to be clever and assuming that it knows what you mean (as opposed to do what you write).

Any expression that evaluates to non-zero is considered true. Those items that start with a letter cannot (implicitely) be converted to a number thus it's considered zero and therfor "false". I would think that items that have the (character) value `'0'` are also excluded.

The following statement for example will happily delete all rows in your table:

```
DELETE FROM foobar
WHERE 42;
```

You cannot turn this behaviour off. Not even in ANSI mode will MySQL throw a syntax expression.

Comment: This is also non-zero `SELECT * FROM `test` t where 0.4;` but doesn't considered as true.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause is waiting for a BOOLEAN, I don't now how mysql manage numeric varchar, but I think mysql may assume numeric starting string are equivalent to true.
It may interpret the query as

```
SELECT * 
  FROM items im
  WHERE ItemNumber IS TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports this boolean thing that should be dropped. It leads to confusion and will return wrong/unexpcted result. No other RDBMS supports this. Suppose you have a procedure with a parameter and you forget to specify it like below

```
WHERE col
```

It will return all data and it is very difficult to debug

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should compare ItemNumber with something. Or try

```
WHERE ItemNumber NOT NULL
```

or something like

```
WHERE ItemNumber != ''
```